# Negate the statement u + v < w

Tags: real-analysis, logic

The statement is
"there is $u \in \mathbb R$ such that for all $v \in\mathbb R$ there exists $w\in\mathbb R$ such that $u + v < w$".

I know that $\text{not}[\forall x,\exists y,P(x,y)]\iff \exists y,\forall x,\text{not}P(x,y)$.

If it weren't for the $u$, following the formula above would be easy for "$v < w$". How do I deal with the $u$ ?

Comment: No, your negation is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want

$$\text{not}(\exists u\in \mathbb R,\quad\forall v\in \mathbb R,\quad\exists w\in \mathbb R,\quad u+v<w).$$

The negation is:

$$\forall u\in \mathbb R,\quad\exists v\in \mathbb R,\quad\forall w\in \mathbb R,\quad u+v\geqslant w.$$

Comment: I see. In words, would it be "For all u ∈ R there exists v ∈ R such that w ∈ R such that u + v⩾ w"?

Comment: @marble You are right.